# WordPress is down after Google Cloud Platform VM instance IP changed, Unable to SSH

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform, wordpress, google-compute-engine, ssh-keys

**My WordPress website is down after I restarted VM instance of Google Cloud Platform. It had Ephemeral IP, I find out my External IP has been changed!**

Old IP address: 35.200.58.194
New IP address for instance: 35.187.215.2 (Now I made it Static IP)

*When I open New IP address, it shows error "This site can’t be reached".*

I've deployed "WordPress Google Click to deploy" on VM Instance.
OS: Debian 9.12

Now, I just want to recover my website. How can I do that?

Even I'm unable to SSH from Google Console, it's also stopped working. I'm able to access Google Cloud Shell. I've Run this command in Cloud Shell:

```
gcloud beta compute ssh --zone "myzone" "vminstance" --project "projectname"
```

It gives this error:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
(gcloud.beta.compute.ssh) [/usr/bin/ssh] exited with return code 255.
```

I don't want to lose my website, I'm a beginner and worked really hard for this website! Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If you cannot connect to the VM due to a "Permission denied (publickey)" error, this usually indicates that the VM is unable to validate the public key used for user authentication of the account you are using to login.

To remove they key:

- To remove the key that is stored in `/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`, run: `gcloud beta compute os-login ssh-keys remove --key-file=/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`
- To remove the key with fingerprint 'e0d96d6fad35a61a0577f467940509b5aa08b6dea8d99456ec19a6e47126bc52', run: `gcloud beta compute os-login ssh-keys remove --key='e0d96d6fad35a61a0577f467940509b5aa08b6dea8d99456ec19a6e47126bc52'`
- To remove the SSH public key 'AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAAB…ZrPg+DZJIwPab2wPlveLh+ut1Lxs5QTR/9QfEa7', run: `gcloud beta compute os-login ssh-keys remove --key='AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAAB…ZrPg+DZJIwPab2wPlveLh+ut1Lxs5QTR/9QfEa7'`

In relation to not being able to access the WordPress installation, I would attempt to reestablish connectivity to the VM first, and check the web server (Apache/Nginx/Lightspeed/etc) service has started, and there is no firewall filtering preventing access. Once this has been done, confirm that your internal IP address has not changed. If it has, follow the steps in the [this Q&A](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/24938/cant-login-after-my-site-was-moved-to-a-new-server) on [WordPress Development - StackExchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/).

Links:

- https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/compute/os-login/ssh-keys/remove
- https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/24938/cant-login-after-my-site-was-moved-to-a-new-server